# Prove the statement about a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. For $A \subseteq X$ und $x \in X$ we define $d_A : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by \begin{equation*}d_A(x):=\inf\{d(x,y)\mid y\in A\}\end{equation*}

I want to prove the below statement:

> $A$ is closed iff for all $x\in X$ with $d(x,A)=0$ it holds that $x\in A$.

$$$$

Since $A$ is closed, it holds that $\forall x\in X\setminus A : \exists \epsilon >0 : B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A=\emptyset$.

A ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is the set of all points $y\in X$ satisfying $d(x,y)<\epsilon$.

Is the definition correct so far? How could we continue?

For the other direction:

We suppose that $\forall x\in X : d(x,A)=0\Rightarrow x\in A$. By definition it holds that $\displaystyle{d(x,A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}d(x, a_n)}$ and so it holds that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}d(x, a_n)=0}$. Does this mean that all limit points of $A$ are contained in $A$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A$ is closed. Then, if $x\in A$, we have $d_A(x)=0$. And if $x\notin A$, then, since $A$ is closed and therefore $A=\overline A$, $x\notin\overline A$. So, by the definition of closure, there is a $r>0$ such that $B_r(x)\cap A=\emptyset$. Therefore, $d_A(x)\geqslant r$.

And if $A$ is not closed, you take some $x\in\overline A\setminus A$. Then $d_A(x)=0$, but $x\notin A$.

Comment: At the first case why do we get $d_A(x)\geq r$ ? I got stuck righ tnow.

Comment: If $y\in A$, then $y\notin B_r(x)$ and therefore $d(x,y)\geqslant r$. Since $d_A(x)=\inf\{d(x,y)\mid y\in A\}$, $d_A(x)$ is the infimum of a set of numbers all of which are greater than or eqaul to $r$. So, $d_A(x)\geqslant r$.

Comment: Ah ok! At the case where $A$ is not closed how do we get that $d_A(x)=0$ ? Or do we assume that this holds?

Comment: Since $x\in\overline A$, there are points of $A$ as close to $x$ as you wish. So, $d_A(x)=0$.